# Order Xml item by date from XPath query

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, max

I'm writing some perl scripts that reads from an Xml file through XPath query.
From Perl scripts, I need to return the 3 movies with the most recent date ( similar to order film by date ).

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="films.xsl"?>
<collection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://...." xs:schemaLocation="http://.. films.xsd">

<film id="1">
    <title>Title1</title>
    <date>2011-09-24</date>
    <family>Action</family>
</film>
<film id="4">
    <title>Title2</title>
    <date>1980-09-24</date>
    <family>Thriller</family>
</film>

</collection>
```

How can I do?? I read and try more solutions but anything.

I try

```
my $nodeset = $xp->findnodes(
"/collection/film[not(\@id < preceding-sibling::collection/film[\@id] ) and not(\@id < following-sibling::collection/film[\@id])]" );
```

i try the max function of XPath 2.0 only to return the most recent,
i try xsl

```
<xsl:for-each select="collection/film/date">
<xsl:sort select="." data-type="date" order="descending"/>
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the latest film using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::XSH2;

xsh << 'end;';
    open films.xml ;
    register-namespace xs http://.... ;
    $films := hash xs:date /xs:collection/xs:film ;
    $latest = { ( sort { $films->{$a} cmp $films->{$b} }
                     keys %$films )[0] } ;
    ls xsh:lookup('films', $latest) ;
end;
```